# Getting matrix from data using pandas or python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matrix

How can I write  pandas or python code to obtain matrix from my data? I have the following table:

```
Item    Route   Order
R124    A1  1
R124    A2  2
R124    A3  3
R124    A4  4
R124    A4  4
R126    A5  1
R126    A6  2
R126    A7  3
R126    A7  3
```

My required output is:

```
    A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7
R124    1   1   1   2   0   0   0
R126    0   0   0   0   1   1   2
```

To obtain the matrix, a unique 'Item' value becomes a row name. For example R124 has 1 entry each in the 'Order' column mapping to A1, A2 and A3 in the 'Route' column, and 2 entries mapping to A4 in the 'Route' column. The number of mapped entries are recorded accordingly. Since R124 has no 'Order' entry mapping to 'Route' column for A5, A6 and A7, zeros are recorded as shown in the output matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `pivot_table`.

If your data frame is df:

```
df.pivot_table(index="Item",columns="Route",values="Order",aggfunc='count')
```

gives:

```
Route   A1   A2   A3   A4   A5   A6   A7
Item                                    
R124   1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
R126   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  2.0
```

and to completely mimic your desired answer just add `fillna` and `astype`:

```
df.pivot_table(index="Item",columns="Route",values="Order",aggfunc='count').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

gives

```
Route  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7
Item                             
R124    1   1   1   2   0   0   0
R126    0   0   0   0   1   1   2
```

Comment: Excellent!. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks @tvashtar